# React router not mounting component on redirect in Chrome

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, react-router

I'm using react router v4.2 and it looks like Redirect inside Switch does not trigger the component mounting. I'm not using any state management library so it's just pure react code and the bug looks like happens only in chrome!
This is my app component with routing:

```
const App = () => (
    <section id="content">
        <div className="container">
            <Switch>
                <Redirect exact from='/' to='/entries/voto'/>
                <Route path="/entries/:order" component={EntryList}/>
            </Switch>
       </div>
    </section>
)
export default App;
```

If I enter the website url with `'/'` the supplied url (`/entries/voto`) shows up in the browser but no lifecycle method is called, not even the constructor, so I believe nothing depends on the `EntryList` component, which does not implements the `shouldComponentUpdate` method.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure but could you please change your code something like this

```
const App = () => (
<section id="content">
    <div className="container">
        <Switch>
            <Redirect exact from='/' to='/entries/voto'/>
            <Route path="/entries/:order" render={ props => <EntryList {...props}/>}/>
        </Switch>
   </div>
</section>
 )
 export default App;
```

i change `component` and replace it with `render` . in some scenario it's helpful

Comment: @vittoriomaiullari can you create a fiddle or jsbin

Comment: I can do it tomorrow but thing is it happens only in chrome and the app works when in Chrome anonymous mode, so i guess it is something depending on Chrome behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. In my case, I had to put the `Redirect` element after the `Route` element.

Something like this works in my app.

```
return (<div>
          <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginContainer}/>
            {this.props.location.pathname !== '/login'&&
                <Redirect exact from="/" to={"/login"} />
            }
        </div>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody but it looked like it's a chrome cache issue! I tried the app in incognito mode and on a brand new chrome install and it worked fine.